# WillPopScope doesn't work anymore with Flame 1.0.0-releasecandidate.14

Tags: flutter, flame

My code was working before Flame update (from rc8 to rc14) and Flutter update (from 2.2.3 to 2.5.1) but now I can't detect the back button pressed of Android phones.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
return WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () async {            
    if (!endGame) {
      game.pauseGame = !game.pauseGame;
    }
    return false;
  },
  child: Material(...),
);
```

Is there a new function with this version of Flame ? Or in this version of Flutter ?

Comment: Since this is pure Flutter code it is unrelated to Flame, I can't see any changes they have done on the Flutter side regarding `WillPopScope`.

Comment: Is `onWillPop` called at all? Have you tried debugging/adding a print statement?

Comment: Yes I tried but nothing happen... In ohter pages I have in my app, it's working properly but then since the update it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @PierrickG please provide a complete MWE so we can reproduce the issue

Comment: Have you tried this with v1.2.1 @PierrickG?

Comment: Yes, it's working now, I've rebuild completly my games because I started developping with Flame 0.2 which is completly different from 1.X